# Como hacer para que esta funcion se reinicie al llegar al final

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

necesito su ayuda.
Tengo esta funcion en jquery que hace desaparecer un div y hace aparecer la siguiente, pero al llegar al final me gustaria que la funcion se regrese al primer div, tipo slider.

```
 $('div[xx="deporte"]').hide(); // hide all slides
                  $('div[xx="deporte"]:first-child').show(); // show first slide
                  setInterval(function () {
                        $('div[xx="deporte"]:first-child').hide()
                              .next('div[xx="deporte"]').show()
                              .end().appendTo('body');
                  },
            5000); // slide duration
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el concepto de recursividad, crea una función y coloca todo dentro y al final llama a la misma función:

Ejemplo:

```js
function hide_slides(){
  $('div[xx="deporte"]').hide(); // hide all slides
  $('div[xx="deporte"]:first-child').show(); // show first slide
  setInterval(function () {
    $('div[xx="deporte"]:first-child').hide()
    .next('div[xx="deporte"]').show()
    .end().appendTo('body');
  },5000); // slide duration
  
   //Cunado termine todo el código de arriba se llama a si misma la función
   
   hide_slides()
}
```

Intenta a ver si soluciona tu problema.

Comment: No funciona, despues del primer slider no se muestra nada mas

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en `Javascript` pero podrías usar un `while` definiendo la cantidad de veces que vas a realizar la función

```
n = 0;
while (n < 3) {
hide_sides();
n ++;
}

function hide_slides(){
$('div[xx="deporte"]').hide(); // hide all slides
$('div[xx="deporte"]:first-child').show(); // show first slide
setInterval(function () {
$('div[xx="deporte"]:first-child').hide()
.next('div[xx="deporte"]').show()
.end().appendTo('body');
},5000); // slide duration

}
```

Cuéntame si mi respuesta fue acertada.

Comment: Tampoco funciona. En realidad no necesito tener una cantidad de veces definida para ejecutar la funcion. Debe ejecutarse en un loop infinito. Porque lo que hace es pasar de un div a otro y  cuando llega al ultimo div se detiene. Lo que quiero es que vuelva al primero.

Comment: Si, entiendo tu punto, pero creo que con el while seria lo mas acertado, solo que en lugar de tener una cantidad definida podrías poner una variable en la condición del while y dentro del while incrementarla en uno cada vez que este se ejecuta, logrando que sea infinito.

Answer (score 0):

si necesitas pasar por las etiquetas hat una opcion muy valida y es usar el each de jquery.

```
$('#IngresarForm input').each((key, value)=>{
console.log(value)
})
```

creo que es algo asi, eso te retornara los inputs de un formulario

Answer (score 0):

Si pones first-child dentro de la función del intervalo no se si vas a poder.
Podes declarar una int, usar la pseudoclase nth-child() y un pequeño if para reiniciarlo,
te quedaría algo como:

```
var contador=1;
setInterval(function () {
    $('div[xx="deporte"]:nth-child('+contador+')').hide()
      .next('div[xx="deporte"]').show()
      .end().appendTo('body');
    if(contador==$('div[xx="deporte"]').length)contador=1;
    else contador++;
  },
  5000);
```

Me desconcierta el appendTo('body') así que no estoy seguro de cómo funciona tu markup, pero podés aplicar el mismo concepto de la manera que necesites. c: